# Move Prior Texts In Array Below Latest Text Instead of Being Overwritten

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

**What we have now:** So the texts (or sentences) in the `array` will show every `onClick` action. The prior texts will be overwritten by the latest texts.

**What we want to achieve:** Rather than being overwritten, I want all the prior texts to simply move down below the latest texts. Imagine a chat convo where the previous messages simply go down below the latest message in order. I hope it's possible.

**What is this for:** I want to make like a simple storybook for my little girl. She easily gets overwhelmed by too much words in books and loses interest. I want her to be able to read offline too. So I will definitely appreciate it if we can keep it in `vanilla javascript`.

This may be easy for most, but I am just like in a primary level right now when it comes to coding. I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge. But thank you to anyone who can help me.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" id="myBtn">Next</button>
<br><br>
<span id="myText"></span>
```

**Vanilla Javascript**

```
<script>
var texts = [
"text/sentence 1",
"text/sentence 2",
"text/sentence 3",
"text/sentence 4",
"text/sentence 5"
];
var text = document.getElementById("myText");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btn.addEventListener("click", changeText);
text.innerHTML = texts[0];


function changeText() {
    var searchTerm = text.innerHTML;
    var index = texts.indexOf(searchTerm) + 1;
    if (index == texts.length) index = 0;
    var result = texts[index];
    text.innerHTML = result;
    return;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider a variable which store all the texts which have been read. Thus upon a new text, create the new string with that text to which you concatenate the variable (below named `str`)

```js
var texts = [
"text/sentence 1",
"text/sentence 2",
"text/sentence 3",
"text/sentence 4",
"text/sentence 5"
];
var text = document.getElementById("myText");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btn.addEventListener("click", changeText);
let str = '<p>'+texts[0]+'</p>';
text.innerHTML = str

let index = 1
function changeText() {
  str = '<p>' + texts[index] + '</p>' + str
  myText.innerHTML = str
  index = (index + 1) % texts.length 
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="myBtn">Next</button>
<br><br>
<div id="myText"></div>
```

If you are lazy, you can directly use `text.innerHTML` without the auxilliary variable:

```
myText.innerHTML = '<p>'+currentText+'</p>' + myText.innerHTML
```